# How to remove this server managment section from STS 3.7.1 toolbar?

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, ide, spring-tool-suite

I have installed the new version of Spring Tool Suite (STS 3.7.1 version) and I am going totaly crazy trying to eliminate this section (the one selected in red) from the **toolbar**

[image]

As you can see into the toolbar there is this section to run the server. I want delete it because it takes up too much space on the laptop screen.

I have try to go into: **Window ---> Perspective ---> Customize Perspective ---> Toolbar visibility** (that I think should represent all the thing that are shown into the tool bar). So I try to deselect all the voices in this section but this section remain into my toolbar (all the other tool are removed from the tool bar)

Wjhy? What am I missing? How can I remove this cumbersome section from my toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I installed some JBoss tools, I too had this show and couldn't get rid of it until...

On Windows:

From the menu bar select Help -> Install New Software...

Click on link in the line "What is already installed?" (already installed is underlined)

Click on "JBoss Tools Server LaunchBar Integration" and click on the "Uninstall" button.
[JBoss LaunchBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKrZe.png)

Do the restart

BTW, it looks to be a part of the install package of "JBoss Web and Java EE Development
[JBoss LaunchBar Install Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icSXd.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is a separate feature called the "launchbar", I think. It doesn't come with STS pre-installed, it looks like you installed it afterwards (or it came via another additional plugin). I think it got implemented somewhere in the CDT project (but I might be wrong here).

You should be able to completely uninstall that feature (via the About dialog, installation details).